# sed – search for special characters like underscore and replace with dashes

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm looking for solution to replace "`_`" symbols with "`-`".

```
  383 =>.
  array (                   
    'url' => 'order-samsung_s5-online-en.html',
    'module' => 'product',  
    'action' => 'get',      
    'oid' => '14',          
    'lang' => 'en'
```

and after replacement it should look like this:

```
  383 =>.
  array (                   
    'url' => 'order-samsung-s5-online-en.html',
    'module' => 'product',  
    'action' => 'get',      
    'oid' => '14',          
    'lang' => 'en'
```

There may be other underscore("`_`") symbols in the text file, but replacement should only happen within the URLs, between `'url' => 'order-` and `-online`.

Comment: change your sample to have a few `_` after `online` as well.. it will better show your requirement..

Answer (score 2):

With sed, you can use the `t`(test) command to process all `_` found between your strings.

When a substitution succeeds, `ta` will loop to the beginning of the script(`:a`) to search and replace remaining `_`:

```
sed ":a;s/\('url' => 'order-[^_]*\)_\(.*-online\)/\1-\2/;ta;" file
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted. (Although I haven't actually tested it!)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `awk` that replaces character only between the two strings. I have assumed the first one is always at the beginning of row.

```
awk '/^(\047)url(\047) => (\047)order-/ {
        i=index($0,"-online")
        interesting=substr($0,0,i-1)
        gsub(/_/,"-",interesting)
        $0=interesting substr($0,i)
} 1' file
```

- (`\047`) is octal value for single quote used for escaping.
- `index()` returns the index of first occurence of the string in row (or zero if not found)
- `substr()` until this index gives the interesting part
- `gsub()` replaces character in string and assigns the result to it.
- `1` prints the row

test file

```
some_text
'url' => 'order-word_word1-online-es.html',
'url' => 'order-word_word1_word2-online-es.html',
'url' => 'order-word_word1_word2_word3-online-es.html', some_text
some_text
'url' => 'order-word_offline.html'
```

output

```
some_text
'url' => 'order-word-word1-online-es.html',
'url' => 'order-word-word1-word2-online-es.html',
'url' => 'order-word-word1-word2-word3-online-es.html', some_text
some_text
'url' => 'order-word_offline.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest I could do was this:

```
grep -i "^'url' => 'order-" t.txt | sed -e 's/\([[:alnum:]]*\)[_]/\1-/g'
```

this needs grep to find lines starting with
'url' => 'order-
and this WILL substitute every underscore found in this line. This will not stop after
-online

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well the requirement, you can try this sed

```
sed -E '/order/!b;s//&\n/;s/online/\n&/;h;s/\n.*\n/\n/;x;s/[^\n]*\n([^\n]*).*/\1/;s/_/-/g;x;G;s/([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)\n(.*)/\1\3\2/' infile
```

first separate the text between order and online on the line that contain order.

operate the substitution from _ to - on this line.

rearrange the complete line.

cat infile

```
  383 =>.
  array (                   
    'url' => 'order-samsung_s5-online-en.html',
    'module' => 'product',  
    'action' => 'get',      
    'oid' => '14',          
    'lang' => 'en'
```

output

```
383 =>.
array (                   
  'url' => 'order-samsung-s5-online-en.html',
  'module' => 'product',  
  'action' => 'get',      
  'oid' => '14',          
  'lang' => 'en'
```

Comment: It works! but it clones every string of the file. All except  the target string.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to say. So I update my answer with test input file and output.

Comment: Sorry. Samples was added

Comment: @vnr You must edit the question and update the input file, so, this way, all can see the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Question was edited. Can you check one more problem please? [link](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/1223/7891626021.png)